# A web component inside the template of another

Tags: dart

I have a custom element, which is extended by 2 other custom elements

```dart
import 'dart:html';

void main() {
  document.registerElement('x-c', C);
  document.registerElement('x-b', B);

}

class ViewBase extends HtmlElement{
  TemplateElement t;
  ViewBase.created():super.created(){
    t = this.querySelector('template');
    var clone = t.content.clone(true);
    this.createShadowRoot();
    this.shadowRoot.append(clone);
  }
}

class B extends ViewBase{
  B.created():super.created();
}

class C extends ViewBase{
  C.created():super.created();
}
```

when i try to do something like the following

```dart
<x-b>
    <template>
       <p>this is a paragraph in b shadowroot</p>
       <x-c>
         <template>
            <p>this is a paragraph in c shadowroot</p>
         </template>
       </x-c>
    </template>
 </x-b>
```

the nested C element constructor never gets called when the super constructor activates the template inside the B element, any idea why?

what i expect to see on the page is

```dart
this is a paragraph in b shadowroot
this is a paragraph in c shadowroot
```

what i get is only

```dart
this is a paragraph in b shadowroot
```

Comment: I think your usage of <template> and your clone stuff is broken. Why don't you use the `PolymerElement` class?

Comment: @Robert the problem is i see nothing wrong with my above code, could you please explain where its broken?, this is of course just a simple example, my idea is to be able to override the default template which is in another html file, and if i wanted to use polymer i would not have asked ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `document.importNode` instead of `clone`

```dart
import 'dart:html';

void main() {
  document.registerElement('x-c', C);
  document.registerElement('x-b', B);
}

class ViewBase extends HtmlElement {
  TemplateElement t;
  ViewBase.created() : super.created() {
    print("ViewBase, ${this.runtimeType}");
    var shadow = this.createShadowRoot();
    shadow.append(document.importNode((this.querySelector('template') as TemplateElement)
        .content, true));
  }
}

class B extends ViewBase {
  B.created() : super.created() {
    print("B, ${this.runtimeType}");
  }
}

class C extends ViewBase {
  C.created() : super.created(){
    print("C, ${this.runtimeType}");
  }
}
```

I changed your code a bit while playing around. You can of course use temporary variables like in the code in your question, instead of all in one line like I did.

See also
- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/template/
- http://webcomponents.org/articles/introduction-to-template-element/
- http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#Core-Document-importNode